# A sum involving binomial coefficients and powers of 2

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am interested in a simplified version of the following sum 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k-1}.$$
I have to evaluate it for values of n ranging from $10^{4}$ till $10^{10}.$
Is there a way to express it in terms of some special function computable through Matlab or mathematica?

UPDATE : For small values of $n$ I noticed that the value is quite close to $−log_2(n).$

Comment: The **denominators** of $S_n$ form [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A158467).

Comment: @Lucian I did not quite understand your comment. Can you please explain a little more? What is $Sn$ ?

Comment: Your sum, which depends on *n*.

Comment: @Lucian Sorry I am not clear again, what do you mean by denominator of $S_n$ ? $\prod_{k=1}^n (2^k-1)$ ?

Comment: The denominator in its simplified form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite the sum using a geometric series, then apply the binomial theorem:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k-1}&=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{mk}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{m}}\right)^n-1\right].
\end{align*}
In a sense this made things worse, because we replaced the finite sum with an infinite one. On the other hand, the infinite series is nice because:

- the terms are all negative and increase monotonically to $0$, and
- the terms decay exponentially once $m$ is bigger than $\log_2(n)$.

For $n$ large, terms in the series are very close to $-1$ when $m$ is less than $\log_2 n$ and very close to $0$ when $m$ is greater than $\log_2 n$. With some care, this is enough to show that the sum never differs from $-\log_2(n)$ by more than $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Newton's Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)  we can obtain a lower bound
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k-1} \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}=-1+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}=-1+(1-\frac{1}{2})^n=-1+\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: So here you have approximated the denominator of each term $2^k-1\approx 2^k.$ Will it be possible to have some other form of approximation?

Comment: Unfortunately this approximation $-1+(1/2)^n$ is very inaccurate, because as $n$ grows it approaches $-1$, while apparently the absolute value of the formula increases about logarithmically with $n$. For example, f(10)=-3.7255593, f(100)=-6.98380, f(1000)=-10.2993.

Comment: Another thing you can do is approximate $\frac{1}{2^k-1}$ as $\frac{k}{2^{k-1}}$, and get something like $-1-\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: For small values of $n$ I noticed that the value is quite close to $-log_2(n).$ hoping this information might help :)!

Comment: Yes, for example $f(1000)/\log_2(1000)= -1.0334$ and $f(10000)/\log_2(10000)= -1.0250$.

Comment: Perhaps the Taylor series of $log(1+x)$ could be helpful

Comment: @GiovanniResta can you please tell me how you calculated $f(10^4)$ ? Which software did you use ?

Comment: The approximation with (1- 1/2)^n was very elegant, but I did not understand how the -1 left the denominator and got subtracted from the overall sum

Comment: The `-1` in the denominator was neglected, the `-1` in the sum is because the binomial sum in Newton's Binomial theorem starts from 0 and not 1

Comment: @Coniferous I used Mathematica.  The problem here is that the intermediate addends are very large. In general, the largest term (abs.value) is when $k=n/3$. For example, for $n=10000$ and $k=3333$ the term is about $-6.9\cdot 10^{1758}$. The sum is alternating, there is huge cancellation, so the intermediate results NEED to be computed with a very large precision  or the final result will be meaningless. In C language, you can use the GMP library. Be really careful because in some languages you got arbitrary precision integers by default, but not arbitrary precision floating-point numbers.